# OSC 8 styled hyperlinks in the Terminal

Tags: terminal

Is there a way to make the Terminal support the [OSC 8](https://github.com/Alhadis/OSC8-Adoption/) styled hyperlinks?

This,

```bash
printf '\033]8;;http://example.com\033\\This is a link\033]8;;\033\\\n'
```

Just prints out `This is a link`. But it is not clickable.

Comment: Terminal isn’t an HTML renderer.  However, iTerm2 does have limited capabilities of rendering links.

Comment: The question isn't about rendering HTML.

Comment: I agree with @Allan here, from [where you took the command line](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda), it states *"The result is equivalent to this HTML link"*. Have you even ***read*** the title of the article? *"Hyperlinks (a.k.a. HTML-like anchors) in terminal emulators"*

Comment: [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) are majorly used in the terminal to colour text. The link the body gives a [list of terminal emulators](https://github.com/Alhadis/OSC8-Adoption/#terminal-emulators) that render this _Operating System Command 8_ as a proper hyper link. "Have you even read the title of the article?" yes, I am sorry, but did you read past the title of the one I linked? Quoting the first line, "This document tracks in-the-wild support for terminal hyperlinks (a.k.a., OSC 8), **primarily amongst terminal emulators.**"

Comment: Ok, so what’s the question here.  The link you supplied lists several terminal emulators including iTerm2 that do what you’re looking for; Apple’s Terminal isn’t one of them.  Do you believe there’s a hidden setting that enables this feature?

Comment: Features can sometimes be installed, implemented and/or enabled. "Do you believe there’s a hidden setting that enables this feature?" I don't know, hence, "Is there a way to make the Terminal support the OSC 8 styled hyperlinks?"

Answer (score 1):

This has come up before (see [Is there a way to make a link clickable in the OSX Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338765/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-link-clickable-in-the-osx-terminal), [Configure OS X Terminal to detect URLs and make them clickable?](https://superuser.com/questions/654116/configure-os-x-terminal-to-detect-urls-and-make-them-clickable)), and it seems not to be possible to use OSC 8 in macOS Terminal.

It also isn't required. You can just double-click with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> pressed on any URL shown in a Terminal window to have it open in the default browser.

You can use Terminal capabilities to underline text with `tput`

```
tput smul; echo https://apple.stackexchance.com/; tput rmul
```

but this might be confusing because the click behavior is not the same as in a browser.

Comment: Yeah, that feature should be added

Comment: The OSC 8 style does not just make hyperlinks clickable, it also allows you to show a [label](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/460189/494729) instead of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/460189/494729. See? The questions you linked are almost a decade old so I hoped that maybe there was an update or some new way.